# How to reset an setCustomValidity on Lightning:Input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My problem is that it work to set a setCustomValidity on an Lighning:Input element like described here: [Solved](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229878/how-to-set-setcustomvalidity-on-lightninginput)

The problem is that it is not possible to reset this value onces it is set. Even if I get the correct values the error message do not dissapear if the value was once set to a wrong one.

here is my js code:

```
var lines = component.get('v.lines');
var inputField = event.getSource();
var inputvalue = event.getSource().get("v.value");

if (inputvalue < lines[0].kalabis__DeliveryDate__c) {
    console.log('its to small');
    inputField.setCustomValidity('wrong');
} else {
    console.log('its ok');
    inputField.setCustomValidity('');
    component.set('v.isLoaded', false);
    component.set('v.isLoaded', true);
}

inputField.reportValidity();
```

No idea if there is a possibilitty to reset this value but it seems to me very weird.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

## Workaround

Hi @utm, I've found workaround. If you wrap your component inside IF statement and switch on and off, it will force component to re-render.

With this hack it will work just fine.

### Example

```
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoaded}">
        <lightning:input ... />
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            loading...
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
```

Now you need to call `component.set('v.isLoaded', false);` and then `component.set('v.isLoaded', true);` forcing `lightning:input` to re-render.

Message will disappear.

Hope it helps,

Daniel

Comment: Very good idea! Thx. What's still missing is the following: 3 lines with dates. You change line 2 to error state -> Shows error, you change line 3 to error state -> Show error. Everything good for now. But if you now change just one of those lines (e.g. 2nd one) to a "good" state both error states (line 2 and 3) will be cleared

Comment: Pulled from documentation: `reportValidity()`: If the input is invalid, displays the error and returns false. If the input is valid, clears any displayed error and returns true. So, please call `reportValidity()` every time, not only when displaying error.

Comment: I do this. I have updated my code so please take a look. The problem here is still that the lightning:input(s) are in a repeat block. So for one single line your solution works perfectly. But not if you have multiple lines. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to save it with `reportValidity()`. Put it before false/true after line 10.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs][1] they use an example like this:

```
({
    register : function(component, event) {
        var inputCmp = component.find("inputCmp");
        var value = inputCmp.get("v.value");
        // is input valid text?
        if (value === “John Doe”) {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("John Doe is already registered”);
        } else {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity(""); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity(); // Tells lightning:input to show the error right away without needing interaction
    }
})
```

So I would suggest to get the component from an `aura:id` like that:

```
var inputCmp = component.find("inputCmp");
```

and in your markup - set the component with the aura:id:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" type="date" name="date" class="nolabel" value="{!line.CustomField__c}" messageWhenBadInput="Date must be newer than..." onchange="{!c.checkIfValid}" />
```

Comment: But this is exactly what I do. And I also took the example code but it is not working

Comment: From the code you uploaded - it does not seem to look like you did it in the same way, if you did, please update the code so we can help you on your problem

Comment: Hi @ItaiShmida. You can get component by calling `event.getSource()`. Problem me and also @utm are facing is that `inputCmp.setCustomValidity("");` don't do anything. The error won't go away, but field will be valid.

Comment: @DanielHorký thats exactly what I mean. I think it has something to do with the render process.

Comment: To add here. It doesn't have any difference using `event.getSource()` or `component.fing('auraIdOfField')`